# SELECT if array column is NULL or DOESN'T contain input value in Supabase

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I want to write an SELECT statement using Supabase-JS library, where it would return all rows whose `associated_campaigns` (array of UUIDs) column is either `null` or doesn't contain input string.

I'm trying with something like this, where `campaign_id` is input parameter, but without success:

```
supabase.from("linkedin_leads").select("*").or(`associated_campaigns.is.null,not(associated_campaigns.cs.${campaign_id})`);

Error returned is:
"failed to parse logic tree ((associated_campaigns.is.null,not(associated_campaigns.cs.e04a95fc-47bd-4c88-8e97-ad48711ee8d9)))"
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs for [`contains`](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/contains), it looks like you might have to wrap your `campaign_id` in `{}` like this:

```js
supabase.from("linkedin_leads")
  .select("*")
  .or(`associated_campaigns.is.null,not(associated_campaigns.cs.{${campaign_id}})`);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the python user (#supabase-py), you can use :

```
supabase.table('my_table').select('*').filter('my_colum','is', 'null').execute().data
```